# Include IN and LIKE operator as a function of abstraction

Tags: php

I'm using this package for BD abstraction. [https://github.com/robsonvleite/datalayer](https://github.com/robsonvleite/datalayer/blob/master/src/DataLayer.php)

How do I include the `IN` and `LIKE` operator in the function below?

Something simple: If I pass a parameter it includes. If no parameter is passed, the operator is not included.

```
public function find(?string $terms = null, ?string $params = null, string $columns = "*"): DataLayer
    {
        if ($terms) {
            $this->statement = "SELECT {$columns} FROM {$this->entity} WHERE {$terms}";
            parse_str($params, $this->params);
            return $this;
        }

        $this->statement = "SELECT {$columns} FROM {$this->entity}";
        return $this;
    }
```

Example query I intend to do with the class:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projetos WHERE titulo LIKE '%{$_GET['busca']}%' AND categoria = '{$_GET['cat']}' AND subcategoria IN ({$_GET['sub']}) AND habilidades LIKE '%{$_GET['hab']}%'  ");
```

Answer (score 0):

One cannot use `IN` while there is no enumeration or alike.

```
public function find(?string $terms = null, ?string $params = null, string $columns = "*"): DataLayer {
    if ($terms) {
        $this->statement = 'SELECT {$columns} FROM {$this->entity} WHERE some_column LIKE "%{$terms}%"';
        parse_str($params, $this->params);
    } else {
        $this->statement = 'SELECT {$columns} FROM {$this->entity}';
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could do a search like this: `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM projetos WHERE titulo LIKE '%{$_GET['busca']}%' AND categoria = '{$_GET['cat']}' AND subcategoria IN ({$_GET['sub']}) AND habilidades LIKE '%{$_GET['hab']}%'  ");
`

Comment: `IN` is useless, while a record only has 1 sub-category; use `=` instead.

Comment: I use IN, when I need to see more than one value in the same column. Example: `WHERE subcategoria IN (7,1,10);`